# Google Analytics SDK for iOS without CocoaPods

Tags: ios, cocoapods, google-analytics-sdk

I want to update **Google Analytics SDK for iOS** in my project but apparently it is not possible to download the SDK anymore without *CocoaPods*? I **do not** want to use CocoaPods, is there a way to download it as a standalone package?

Comment: Follow this: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/sdk-download